# CA0053 unable to load rule assembly rules.dll VS 2017

Tags: code-analysis, rules, .net-framework-version, visual-studio-2017

How to resolve this error

> CA0053  CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly `'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\team tools\static analysis tools\fxcop\rules\rules.dll':` 
>   Could not load file or assembly `'file:///c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\team tools\static analysis tools\fxcop\rules\rules.dll'` or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Tried to remove these tags from the project file, these tags doesn't exist in project file.

```
<CodeAnalysisRuleDirectories>…</CodeAnalysisRuleDirectories> 
<CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories>…</CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories>
```

any other way of fixing this issue

Comment: am having similar issue